# What combination do you use for your polyglot solution?

Tags: polyglot

Those of us who use multiple languages to solve problems can combine them in a lot of ways.  Personally I use PL/SQL, XSLT, JavaScript, and Java plus the pseudo languages HTML, XML, CSS, Ant, and Bash.  What do you use?

Answer (score 2):

Paraphrasing one of my favorite quotes:

> Always write your code as if it were going to be maintained by a homicidal maniac that knows your home address.

Answer (score 0):

I have a D/MySQL/JavaScript[1]/HTML/CPP[2] app.

[1] compile time D template generated
[2] C pre-processor used to generate apache configs and SQL sprocs

Yes, I *am* trying to take things to the insane! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I work on a desktop application, so my alphabet soup looks like: C# and C++ as well as XML and T-SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Java + Clojure works very well as a combination for me.

- Java is good for the low level code that needs to be well optimized. It also gives you access to the huge array of libraries in the Java ecosystem.
- Clojure is great for rapid development of higher level code, working interactively in a REPL. It has great support for meta-programming and concurrency, and I often use Clojure to "glue together" Java based components into a working application.

It helps enormously that Java and Clojure run in the same JVM - calling between the two is very easy and has effectively zero performance overhead.